# Why are American cars less efficient compared to european European/Japan cars

Tags: fuel-consumption, motors

A normal average European car has a engine with less than a 2.0 liter engine which consumes 1 litre of fuel in 18-22 km.

A normal average American car has a engine at least a 2.5 liter engine and gets only 10-12 km with 1 liter of fuel.

Example:
Diesel engine:

- EUR: Ford Focus 1.5 Tdci with 120 HP (http://www.ford.co.uk/ConfigureyourCar/NewFocus/Studio)
- USA: No diesel engine found (http://www.ford.com/cars/focus/specifications/engine/)

Petrol engine (smallest engine found in USA is 2.0L):

- EUR: Ford Focus euro model 1.0L Ecoboost 100 HP (30 km/l delcared)
- USA: Ford Focus 2.0L Ecoboost 160 HP (30 mpg declared)

Example SUV:

- EUR: AUDI Q7 3.0 TDI 245 HP (14 km/l declared)
- EUR: LAND ROVER 3.0 Diesel TDV6 249 HP (15 km/l declared)
- USA: JEEP 3.0L EcoDiesel V6 Engine 240HP (the last model 30mpg, probably fiat engine)
- USA: GMC TERRAIN 3.6L Petrol

I just bring some modern examples but if we go some years in the past the gap would be really bigger.

NOTE: I am just curios about this difference.

EDIT: Right diesel to diesel I mean, that is correct as Paul suggest

EDIT2: the above is just an example, I can bring dosen of examples of cars of same category showing the gap of efficency between usa and europe cars.

Example: one of the most common compact car in USA: AMC Pacer X has a 4.2L engine with just 130Hp.

Comment: You are comparing apples-to-oranges. Why don't you look at diesel-to-diesel comparison, or a petro-to-petro? I think you'll be surprised that your premise is ***WAY*** off base.

Comment: My premise it's true, in general, it is a de-facto situation.

Comment: Someone said to me that this is because in America there are big spaces so cars makes more miles and biggest engine are better for long usage...

Comment: @Paulster2 Yes of course (sorry I just realised), that the compare should be done on same fuel cars.

Comment: Hmmm ... still seems to me in your edit the first car you are quoting is an American car ... Ford is still American owned, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly that is still what makes me curios because ford in usa makes big engines, meanwhile ford Europe has the most efficient small engines. My current car is a ford focus 1.6tdci up to 22km/l

Comment: albanx - your two examples are still not apples to apples. Why not compare a US Ford 2 litre and a European Ford 2 litre. That would make much more sense

Comment: @RoryAlsop I agree with you, but US ford 2L is a car of the last years.

Comment: PLEASE who downvotes as least give a reason

Comment: I was one of the downvoters. My reasons are twofold: this is a simple rehash of a question that was closed by the community, and you are still comparing apples to oranges. It reads like you are trying to shoehorn something in where it may not be valid any more. Certainly Chevrolet now use Daewoo/Opel engines, Ford develop globally, etc.

Comment: yes this is a rehash of a question closed with no reason. It is still valid. Example still here http://www.ford.com/cars/focus/models/ I cannot find a 1.6 diesel engine. So it is valid. I upvoted your answer because it makes sense, seems to be a valid explain

Comment: I downvoted also, but assumed it was VERY self evident. As Rory said, rehash of the same CLOSED question. If you look at my profile, you'll see I do not down vote often. This question was done a little better, but it is still a very poor question and does not fit this site. I believe I know what you *want* to ask, but you still haven't come close to asking it.

Comment: OK I do not made an exact science question, but it was just to show the base concept and the idea guys. That is why I asked here to make a more rich response. You are pointing polemics on how question is done and not on the response. It is just a question that needs a response, not offending anyone. I am curios to hear a response from a European guy...

Comment: @albanx, if you'd like to have an open-ended discussion, please feel free to use the chat.  This area is for asking questions that can be answered.  Please review the guidance in the site tour: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour.  This is not an area for [no true scotsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) arguments.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree that this is a matter of opinion. IF there is still a difference between average economy of US cars vs. European, then there will be a reason for it! Even if it's just a cultural thing.

Comment: @user2808054 thank you. But is really hard to argue with some usa guys here. they said comparing apples to orange but with no argument.

Comment: albanx - [chat] is the place for this. Also, I am Scottish, living in Scotland - so I'm guessing that counts as 'response from European'

Comment: yes of course :). That is why your reply is a valid one and a good one.

Comment: any way I will re-forumulate the question to bring real examples making a compare nearest to apple to apple

Answer (score 3):

Paulster2's comment on your post is absolutely correct. The difference between diesel and petrol is so huge, it completely overshadows the differences between cars in various regions.

That said, there is historical precedence for different typical power/fuel consumption figures in these regions.

The US has long had very cheap fuel, cheap land and extensive heavy industry - which means a simple option for increasing power was to build a bigger engine. This requires more fuel, and often larger vehicles, but building long, straight, wide roads in the US was relatively cheap and convenient (low population density, often farmland or large expanses of plains) - so a 6 litre V8 is not uncommon.

Europe, on the other hand, has higher population density, narrower, twisty roads, and very expensive fuel. Like Japan, this has led to development of higher power density engines, which is why you have ended up with small turbocharged engines around the 2 litre size.

Small engines use less fuel, in general, so the legacy is what has driven the two regions.

These days there is a general move towards smaller engines, hybrids etc, as everyone now sees the rising cost of fuel, but Europe and Japan are still leading the way; Audi for diesels, and Honda (I think it is still) for petrol.

Comment: a 6 litre v8 in europe will be consider a ferrary. Another reason is that there are big spaces in usa and cars are used much more that in europe. Bigger engines with less power probably needs less maintenance and have bigger durability.

Comment: albanx - no. Some Ferraris do have large engines, but this is irrelevant. I already described the land space. The usage is provably incorrect.

Comment: +1 for pointing to economics.  i.e. Gas in the US is and has been really cheap.  There has been little to no incentive for US car companies to innovate or put any premium whatsoever on fuel efficiency until relatively recently.  Those companies are still producing, on average and with certain exceptions, cars that are of ancient design.  Heck, GM still makes and uses 2-valve/cylinder pushrod engines!

Comment: Just an anecdote: I am English. I once followed a 50's Cadillac (extreme example, I know) through one of our medium sized towns. It had to do a 3-point turn just to get around some traffic lights. US roads are so different to ours, it seems larger cars are the right tool for the job in USA. For UK / Europe generally: we need something smaller, as you say, which equates to more economy usually.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I have not seen any ferrari having engine bigger than 5 L, probably there are, but most ferraries have a 3 - 5L engine

Answer (score 1):

Look [in this Car and Driver article](http://blog.caranddriver.com/the-10-most-fuel-efficient-gas-and-diesel-cars-for-sale-today/) from March of this year. You'll notice what the number one mileage car on the road today is (other than hybrids/electric) ... That's right, an **AMERICAN** Chevrolet Cruze at 46mpg (or ~20km/l). This beats out Japanese and European cars alike. You'll notice the Cruze has a 2l diesel engine, like the "average European" car you mention. As I mentioned in my comment, compare apples-to-apples and you'll find your premise is way off base. And remember, the internet has a vast amount of information. Use it wisely.

Comment: In the last years the American cars are approaching Europe ones as consumption and engine but they are still one step after.

Comment: Paulster - that figure appears to be very wrong, or measured very strangely. My wife's car is a 58 mpg car (although she only gets 52 mpg) and it is a cheap Honda.

Comment: @RoryAlsop ... I don't know what figures they are using. I'm sure some people are getting way better fuel mileage. Also figure in hybrids and such, and the numbers get skewed even more. I can only go with what is in print. All else is conjecture. C&D is fairly reputable and trusted as a magazine goes. If you can find something in print which refutes this, I'll gladly back down.

Comment: http://www.nextgreencar.com/best-mpg-cars/ http://www.whatcar.com/car-news/real-world-mpg-efficient-small-cars/1214063 http://www.autoexpress.co.uk/best-cars/62048/most-economical-cars

Comment: heh, and this one at 300mpg http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2540618/The-fuel-efficient-car-world-Volkswagen-XL1-does-300-MILES-gallon-looks-cool-too.html

Comment: http://www.autoguide.com/auto-news/2011/11/top-10-most-fuel-efficient-cars-of-2012.html/10

Comment: @RoryAlsop ... Hybrids are a whole other conversation.

Comment: I agree - I only realised that a couple of them were hybrids after posting. Many of the normally aspirated cars there have high 60's though.